# Installing lo-menubar package for Libreoffice 3.4rc

Tags: unity, libreoffice, appmenu

I've had a problem installing the **lo-menubar** package (Unity integration for LibreOffice menubar). it seems that **lo-menubar** package has assumed 3.3.3 as default version of LibreOffice.

But whenever I delete the `libreoffice` package and make a clean install of the 3.4 package, I can't find any icon of this version.

In the terminal, running `libreoffice3.4` gives this message: "Command not found", but on Synaptic I can see that Libreoffice 3.4 is fully installed.

Could you please give me a help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the **Global menu support** section here:

http://linuxforums.org.uk/ubuntu/upgrading-libreoffice-to-3-4-1-in-ubuntu-11-04/

or download lo-menubar as a LibreOffice extension from here:

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/attachment.cgi?id=47502

and just double-click it to install.

Comment: Change last step: '*and just double-click it to install.*' to right-click and choose 'Open with LibreOffice' (if you have done this before) OR 'Open with Other Application' and choose LibreOffice.